# svg text entity is escaped when set in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, escaping, entity

Edit: I already have the escaped XML string.  I know javascript has a different literal syntax and I am trying to avoid having to convert.

I want to set the text content of an svg text element dynamically in javascript.  But when I use an XML entity in the text content, the entity is escaped.
I realize I could convert the XML escape sequence into literal character, but I don't understand why:

```
 e.textContent="Copyright &#x00a9;";
```

behaves differently from the svg:

```
 <text y="100">Copyright &#x00a9;</text>
```

In the latter the copyright symbol is shown, in the former I see the literal code.

Here is a fiddle that displays the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/AaronDavidNewman/4qs9ug53/10/

Edit:
Based on Michael Kay's answer below, I have posted the solution here:

https://jsfiddle.net/AaronDavidNewman/h6svzn98/3/

The entity needs to be present when the XML is parsed...

```
var dp = new DOMParser();
var tn = dp.parseFromString(...string that contains code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree representation of XML and the lexical representation of XML are quite different things. The DOM contains strings without any XML escaping - the XML parser removes escape sequences while parsing, and a serializer adds escape sequences back when serializing.

The reason that `&#x00a9;` doesn't work is that this notation is understood only by an XML parser, and you're not processing it with an XML parser.

Comment: Thank you, you are right that the escape sequence needs to be present when the XML is parsed. Setting the 'textContent' property does not cause any parsing to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript escaping and XML escaping do not have the same syntax. For javascript the unicode escape prefix is \u

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");    
    e.textContent="Copyright \u00A9";
    document.getElementById("moo-cow").appendChild(e);
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <g id="moo-cow" >
    
  </g>
  <g id="works-fine">
    <text y="100">Copyright &#x00a9;</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize this.  But the string comes to me already with XML escape, and it seems like I should be able to put the entity sequence into the svg xml somehow.  I'll make this clear in the question.

Comment: Xml != JavaScript different languages, different syntax